# route is redirecting to wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what my routes currently look like:

[image: routes.rb]

which gives

[image: rake routes]

On my homepage I have a create vacancy button

```
<%= link_to "plaats", new_employer_vacancy_path(:employer_id)%>
```

Which should be linked to the line from the first image

```
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/new', to: 'vacancies#new', as: 'new_employer_vacancy'
```

In the vacancies_controller#new - create I have:

```
def new
  @vacancy = Vacancy.new
  @employervacancy = Employervacancy.new
end

def create
  @vacancy = Vacancy.create(vacancy_params)
  createEmployervacancy
  redirect_to employer_vacancy_path(current_employer, @vacancy)
end

def createEmployervacancy
  @employer = current_employer
  Employervacancy.create(vacancy_id: @vacancy.id, employer_id: @employer.id)
end
```

But whenever I click the button I get redirected to some other method in my vacancies_controller that is totally irrelevant.

[image: Routing error]

How is this even possible? Don't I clearly define that when that path is clicked he should go to vacancies#new? and not to vacancies#show_specific_employer_vacancies?

**EDIT**

After following the answers I am indeed being linked to the correct route.
First, it gave me this error.

[image: Error]

After trying to pass the current_employer.id instead of @employer like suggested I got following error:

[image: ID error]

Comment: Next, please to add your code here rather than image, especially route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your routes, you'd better to change into nested route for easily maintaining routes.

Remove these codes:

```
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/:id', to:"vacancies#show_specific_employer_vacancies", as: "employer_vacancy"
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/edit/:id' ...
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/index' ...
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/new' ...
path '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/:id' ...
```

change into:

```
resources :employers do
  resources :vacancies
end
```

Try to use basic routes here because you use standard simple form url. For example:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@employee, @vacancy) %>
```

The `simple_form_for` will generate url well if you use nested routes above.

Finally, in your link you have to add `@employer_id`

```
<%= link_to "plaats", new_employer_vacancy_path(:employer_id => @employer_id)%>
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score -1):

Your router cannot tell the difference between your `employer_vacancy` and `new_emplyer_vacancy` routes because the `:id` parameter accepts anything. Because of this, when you point your browser to "*/employers/5/vacancies/new*", the route is taking your `employer_vacancy` route and assigning `{:employer_id => 5, :id => "new"}` **instead of** going to your `new_employer_vacancy` route (because routes are first-come-first-serve).

To correct this, add a constraint to your first route to ensure that only numbers (and not the string "new") is accepted into the `employer_vacancy` route:

```
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/:id',
    to: 'vacancies#show_specific_emplyer_vacancies',
    as: 'employer_vacancy',
    constraints: { id: /\d+/ }                       # <- This line
```

Comment: Thank you, with some tinkering and also adding your solution I am actually one step further now. It is atleast redirecting me to the correct method. Although now I get following https://i.gyazo.com/9916910276f5101c75b84365b783c6b8.png
The error message states that it is looking for an ID that is missing. Although I could not have a clue which ID that could be - employer_id is provided and vacancy_id would just be a new one that is generated with Vacancy.create. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's because you are passing your employer object into the `emoloyer_id` param. Pass the ID using `current_employer.id`

Comment: That would make sense, after trying that I get
undefined method `to_model' for 2:Fixnum
After a quick search results in people saying following:

When you pass xxx.id as a argument, Rails try to guess the path from Fixnum you passed. Since it's impossible, the error is raised.

Comment: Try assigning the `simple_form_for` url directly. For example: `simple_form_for(current_employer, {url: new_employer_vacancy_path()}`. If more errors keep popping up, I suggest you make a new question before these answers becoming irrelevant to the final problem.

Answer (score -1):

As Wes Foster said rails router is trying to find a first match.

It means that given a path `/employers/999/vacancies/new` your router looks through the routes and when it sees `get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/:id` he thinks that this route matches. So `:employer_id` is `999` and `:id` is `new`.

I'd suggest to put the route with :id at the end of employers routes:

```
...
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/new'
...
get '/employers/:employer_id/vacancies/:id'
```

---

Btw this is better than adding a constraint because:

1. It is easier
2. It doesn't pollute routes file
3. Later you may want to change ids to be hashed or alphabetic and then you'd have to change the constraint

Comment: This is fine for simple route files, but as the become more complex, it gets harder and harder to organize lines and ensure one is above the other. You may end up "overwriting" another route when you move one below another, or a conflicting route may be at the top of the file and now you have to move it to the bottom. For simple, it works. I wouldn't say it's "better" than constraints though.

Comment: @WesFoster, the case is rather simple. There is no need for constaints in this case.